# Problem scraping from a dynamically generated page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape data from a social network page. My approach is to scroll down to the end of the page, if there is a button that says "Show more" then I click it and keep scrolling.

The problem is that it scrolls the first time, the button isn't always generated, if you scroll down sometimes you get a button and you must click it to load more content and sometimes simply reaching the end of the page will load the content.

What happens is, I scroll down, the content gets generated and loaded and I'm no longer scrolled to the end of the page. but my code keeps looking for the button and it doesn't find it then I just get an error.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 10

# Get the initial height of the page
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    try:
        # Wait for the "Show more" button to appear
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        show_more_button = wait.\
            until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "scaffold-finite-scroll__load-button")))

        # Check if button is obscured
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(show_more_button).perform()
        show_more_button.click()
    except TimeoutError:
        # Check if page is scrolled all the way down
        is_scrolled_down = driver.\
            execute_script("return window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight")
        time.sleep(2)
        if is_scrolled_down:
            break
```

And I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 60, in 
> show_more_button.click()   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 93, in click
> self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 403, in _execute
> return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 440, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 245, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120) Stacktrace: Backtrace:  (No
> symbol) [0x00F76643]  (No symbol) [0x00F0BE21]    (No symbol)
> [0x00E0DA9D]  (No symbol) [0x00E109E4]    (No symbol) [0x00E108AD]    (No
> symbol) [0x00E10B30]  (No symbol) [0x00E43150]    (No symbol)
> [0x00E369AD]  (No symbol) [0x00E5FD7C]    (No symbol) [0x00E3641F]    (No
> symbol) [0x00E600D4]  (No symbol) [0x00E76B09]    (No symbol)
> [0x00E5FB76]  (No symbol) [0x00E349C1]    (No symbol) [0x00E35E5D]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x011EA142+2497106]  GetHandleVerifier
> [0x012185D3+2686691]  GetHandleVerifier [0x0121BB9C+2700460]
> GetHandleVerifier [0x01023B10+635936]   (No symbol) [0x00F14A1F]    (No
> symbol) [0x00F1A418]  (No symbol) [0x00F1A505]    (No symbol)
> [0x00F2508B]  BaseThreadInitThunk [0x768800F9+25]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77317BBE+286]
> RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77317B8E+238]

I tried adding this before and after clicking the button but to no avail:

```
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(show_more_button))
```